# Excel VBA Code Repeat for rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that I'm using in a survey to create x boxes in only one of a range of C:H when checked.  I am looking to repeat it from the row that this code currently works with (row 3) through row 152, but I am unsure how to get it to work.

How would I go about doing this?  I'm kind of a novice, so any help would be appreciated.

-Chris

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rInt As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("C3:H3"))

If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C3:H3")) > 0 Then
        Range("C3:H3").Value = ""
    End If

    For Each rCell In rInt
       If rCell.Value = "" Then
            rCell.Value = "X"
       ElseIf rCell.Value = "X" Then
            rCell.Value = ""
       End If
    Next
End If

Set rInt = Nothing
Set rCell = Nothing
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, nothing in the code I posted.  I just think I'm not excel sophisticated enough.  ;)  If I try to do a loop command or set another range for 3 to 152 I just can't seem to make it all work.

Comment: Instead of explicitly calling your range, use variables.  e.g. `Range(Cells(3,x),Cells(7,x))` and then you can stick it inside a `For` loop and increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare your row numbers as a variable and then use a `For` loop, like so:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rInt As Range
Dim rCell As Range

For rw = 3 To 152

Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw))

If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw)) > 0 Then
        Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw).Value = ""
    End If

    For Each rCell In rInt
       If rCell.Value = "" Then
            rCell.Value = "X"
       ElseIf rCell.Value = "X" Then
            rCell.Value = ""
       End If
    Next
End If

Set rInt = Nothing
Set rCell = Nothing
Cancel = True

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help @Chris! :)  If my answer worked out, please vote up and/or accept it, so others can see it, too.  Thanks!

Comment: I accepted it but my ranking is too low to vote it up.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries; you're welcome, and thanks to you, too.  Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you code reads:

If the range that was selected intersects with `C3:H3` then, clear the contents of `C3:H3`, then loop through through which ever cells were in the selection that were also in `C3:H3` and set them to "X" (they are all blank so your `If rcell.value = ""` is superfluous).

To loop through C3:H152 applying that same logic (which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to begin with) then change your for loop to `For each rcell in Range("C3:H152")`

This will do that `if` statement against each cell in that range, only when there is an intersection between what was selected and `C3:H3`. I would imagine you'll want to adjust your code a bit to better fit whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I input your suggestions.  You are right in that my rcell.value = "" was superfluous.  Thanks for helping me clean it up.  However, when I changed the range, it just added X's to every cell in that range.  I only want there to be one X per row dependent upon the end user clicking that survey option.